# how to generate html in Go with data from struct

Tags: html, go, go-templates

I have an html like this `email.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Shareholder</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> {{.PageTitle}} </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

and I call like this:

```
func main() {

    theTemplateHTML, err := template.New("").ParseFiles("./pkg/template/email.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(theTemplateHTML)

    type Email struct {
        PageTitle string
    }
    var email Email
    email = Email{
        PageTitle: "Hello Word",
    }
    err = theTemplateHTML.Execute(os.Stdout, &email)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(theTemplateHTML)
}
```

the output got on the first log is  `&{<nil> 0xc0000b0080 <nil> 0xc0000d0050}`

and the last log I got error like this  `template: "" is an incomplete or empty template`

is that the output of html ? and how I can define the `{{.PageTitle}}` in that html with stuct ??

how to correct way to define struct in that html and be able to see the result by string because I want that template to be string ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need the `template.New("")` call. `template.ParseFiles("./pkg/template/email.html")` will work.

Edit: You also need to remove the last `log.Println` line.

Comment: then how to define struct in that html and I want the output is string html ?

Comment: the line to create the template should be  `theTemplateHTML, err := template.New("").ParseFiles("./pkg/template/email.html")` Everything else should be the same.

Comment: how to put the struct then into that ? and the log is still `&{<nil> 0xc0000200c0 0xc000112000 0xc00005c0a0}`

Comment: you do not need the `log.Println(theTemplateHTML)` call. The `err = theTemplateHTML.Execute(os.Stdout, &email)` line prints the contents of the template

Comment: This answer is correct.   See https://play.golang.org/p/TzQv27XN-zR.   Note that the program writes template output to stdout.  Ignore the log output written to stderr.